# Move a node to another computer

Tags: cardano-node

What do I need to do to move a node on one machine to another so the node appears to be the same node. I have a node on one machine but need to discontinue that machine. When I build the new machine out I need it to have the same keys I'm guessing. I'm not exactly sure what files would need to be copied over. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is this for a Stake Pool block producing node?

Answer (score 2):

Based off the "same keys" part of the question, I am going to assume this is for a block producing node.

**Block Producing Node:**

For the BP, all you need to do to move it is copy the **kes.skey, vrf.skey and node.cert**. You will also want to copy your configuration files and make sure your UFW configuration is the same. The last step is, if you changed the IP address, to update your relay topology to connect to the new IP address, as well as update the relay UFW if needed.

**Minting Tokens:**

Although I have not tested this, I believe you need to copy over your **policy.vkey**, **policy.skey**, **policy.script**, and your **policy.ID**. You also may need your payment address and keys. If I am missing anything please correct me and I'll update this.

[Minting Token's Source](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/native-tokens/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond! It's not a block producing node, but I want to be able to mint tokens and make associated metadata (or alter previous metadata) later which requires the "same" node. (that's what I've been lead to believe anyway)

Answer (score 0):

just to be sure,
you need to define what kind of files you store this moment to your old node.
it depends on your folder structure and for what reason the node is running.

i would recommend you to install the same way the new node and use the same folder structure.
then you store the files on the same folder as it is now.
cold.counter*
cold.skey*
cold.vkey*
hot.skey*
hot.vkey*
pool.id
pool.id-bech32
vrf.skey*
vrf.vkey*

kes.start*
op.cert*
pool.cert*
pool.config*
poolmeta.json*

if you run the node as a BP only, and you store the rest of your files on offline system, then our friend before is right,
you need only this 3 files on the node :
kes.skey,
vrf.skey and
node.cert.

[image]